# Triggering a parent function from child using props

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do something simple: I want my child component to trigger a function found in my parent component, and I understand the right way is using props.

In the following Codepen you can find an example:

https://codepen.io/akmur/pen/MvXGEG

Basically what I want to achieve is to print "hey" to console.

This is my code:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  onClickAdd(){
    this.props.addItem();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClickAdd}>Add</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  addItem(){
    console.log('hey');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form addItem={this.addItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `onClickAdd` function. Just call `this.props.addItem` directly onClick (notice, no parens) that you passed down.

```
 class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.addItem}>Add</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  addItem(){
    console.log('hey');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form addItem={this.addItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```